# how to create gridview from dictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a dictionary where key is a String and element is a List

I want to create a group from every key with elements from element. But I don`t know how to make it

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!--
        Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
        of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
    -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        />

</Page.Resources>

<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
      IsSwipeEnabled="True">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"
           Foreground="White" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="Test 123" Foreground="Gold" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </GridView.GroupStyle>
        </GridView>
```

In loop I create the dictionary

```
groups.Add(this.letters[i], items);
```

and after that I have

```
groupedItemsViewSource.Source = groups;
```

But I get nothing. How should I correct this to have a key as group title and every list as a list of elements in this grid ??

// EDIT

Ok I found that making List> instead of Dictionary is better. I get now 3 group headers (cause I got 3 lists in my list) but have no items. IMO this is better way than the first

// EDIT 2
I didn`t see items cause background and foreground were white. Stupid me :) But now I have last problem to solve. How to dynamicly set groups titles ?

Comment: Don't change your question. It makes us shoot at a moving target.

Comment: @Erno sorry I'm just trying to give as many informations as I can

Comment: This is not more information, this is just another question. Imagine some having the same problem as the last one you added. What are the chances he stumbles on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't have to create custom classes to enable grouping. In fact you can use LINQ to do it for you:

> var result = from act in Activities group act by act.Project into grp
>   orderby grp.Key select grp;
>
> cvsActivities.Source = result;

In order to show grouped items in a GridView you must use CollectionViewSource. Just setting the groups as the GridView.ItemsSource will not work. You must set GridView.ItemsSource = a CollectionViewSource and CollectionViewSource must point to the groups. You will also likely have to set CollectionViewSource.IsSourceGrouped = true.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged or INotifyCollectionChanged which is required if you want your binding work

```
public class yourclass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}


ObservableCollection<yourclass> dict = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomClass>();
dict.Add(new yourclass{Key = "yourkey", Value = whatyouwant});
dict.Add(new yourclass{ Key = "yourkey2", Value = whatyouwant });
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I got class of this kind. With key field and value witch is a List<Content> type. But now I get absolutly nothing after binding. Maybe I can send some more code for you so you would have better overview ?

Comment: hi see this project it will help you to understand how bind a grid control http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

Comment: unfortunatly i can`t solve my problem. When I want to bind only items to grid view it`s easy. But I can`t bind grouped objects. For exaple object with key and List<MyObject> as items. I get nothing. Just blank space. No items, no titles :/