# how to structure data fro gridview that is grouped

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How should I make my collection for grouped collection in gridview ?

When I create `List<List<MyObject>>` groups I get grouped data with good count of groups and elements in each group but I have no group titles.
So I've created object MyGroupedObject that has two fields

```
public String Key;
public List<MyObject> items;
```

so I have grouped that in object. But when I pass it to the grid view (like below) I have nothing. No items, no groups no nothing

```
 <Page.Resources>
<!--
    Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
    of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
-->
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
    IsSourceGrouped="true"
    />

</Page.Resources>
```

than in gridview i just bind this collection as ItemsSource

this question is based on: [how to create gridview from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129430/how-to-create-gridview-from-dictionary)

I've created new cause in the original is to many questions so I want to make it all clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Grouping and Semantic Zoom sample? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/groupedgridview-77c59e8e

You can also look at How to group items in a list or grid...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780627.aspx

Short explanation is... you can do it one of two ways...

```
List<Activity> Activities = new List<Activity>(); 
Activities.Add(new Activity() 
    { Name = "Activity 1", Complete = true, 
            DueDate = startDate.AddDays(4), Project = "Project 1" });
Activities.Add(new Activity() 
    { Name = "Activity 2", Complete = true, 
            DueDate = startDate.AddDays(5), Project = "Project 2" });
```

followed by the following to get the data in your CollectionViewSource

```
var result = from act in Activities 
             group act by act.Project into grp 
             orderby grp.Key select grp;
cvsActivities.Source = result;
```

Or you can build a hierarchy using object properties like this...

```
List<Project> Projects = new List<Project>();

Project newProject = new Project();
newProject.Name = "Project 1";
newProject.Activities.Add(new Activity() 
    { Name = "Activity 1", Complete = true, DueDate = startDate.AddDays(4) });
newProject.Activities.Add(new Activity() 
    { Name = "Activity 2", Complete = true, DueDate = startDate.AddDays(5) });
newProject.Activities.Add(new Activity() 
    { Name = "Activity 3", Complete = false, DueDate = startDate.AddDays(7) });
newProject = new Project();
newProject.Name = "Project 2";
newProject.Activities.Add(new Activity() 
    { Name = "Activity A", Complete = true, DueDate = startDate.AddDays(2) });
newProject.Activities.Add(new Activity() 
    { Name = "Activity B", Complete = false, DueDate = startDate.AddDays(3) });
cvsProjects.Source = Projects;
```

You cannot bind to a simple list and have the grouping automatically configured for you.

Comment: but the project example is exactly what I did. you have a object Project with Name (my Key) and Activities (my items). Than I set it for collection as source. this is what I`ve described and it is not working. Thanks for links I'll double check them

Comment: jeff your links and explains were priceless. I found the solution. The problem was one small mistake in my data model and I`ve improved grouping. Now everything works great

Comment: In case it's not clear above, the key is using CollectionViewSource. Just setting this "collection of collections" as the GridView.ItemsSource will not work. You must set GridView.ItemsSource = a CollectionViewSource and CollectionViewSource must point to the "collection of collections". You will also likely have to set CollectionViewSource.IsSourceGrouped = true.

Answer (score 1):

Your Data should be just as described `IList<MyGroupObject>` where MyGroupObject is defined as such

```
class MyGroupObject
{
    public String Key; // used for group title
    public IList<MyObject> Items;
}
```

Then your `CollectionViewSource` should be defined as such

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
    IsSourceGrouped="true"
    Source="{Binding GroupItems}" <!-- Property in the backing ViewModel -->
    ItemsPath="Items" <!-- Property on the MyGroupObject class -->
/>
```

Comment: only diffrence in your code and what I did is that I use in my cs file `groupedItemsViewSrouce.Source = groups` where groups is the list of grouped objects. It does not work :/

Comment: I've also included the `ItemsPath` which is required to see the items in the group

Comment: Yeah I see I already tried this. But I think I'm now on correct path. I've started everything from scratch using yours and Jeff`s advices and I`m starting to getting somewhere